# Inserting code environment in an endnote

Tags: code, endnotes

I am currently writing a report in which I have to include many bits of code in endnotes on a different page. Doing every reference manually seems unnecessarily tedious. I found a way to insert python code and have it look nice but it creates an environment so I can't figure a way to put it in an endnote.

Here is the code used to insert python:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox,listings}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{darkWhite}{rgb}{0.94,0.94,0.94}
 
\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{darkWhite},
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    commentstyle=\color{cyan},
    deletekeywords={...},
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
    extendedchars=true,
    keepspaces=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{orange},
    language=Python,
    morekeywords={*,plot,append,...},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    stepnumber=1,
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    tabsize=4,
    title=\lstname,}
\lstdefinestyle{frameStyle}{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=20pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{black}}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,breakable}
\newtcblisting{customFrame}{
    arc=0mm,
    top=0mm,
    bottom=0mm,
    left=3mm,
    right=0mm,
    width=\textwidth,
    listing only,
    listing options={style=frameStyle},
    breakable}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
```

And here is a minimal exemple of what I would want to create (with code above before `\begin{document}`) :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{enotez}

\begin{document}

Using this method \endnote{} we get...

\pagebreak

\printendnotes
\begin{customFrame}
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
\end{customFrame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance !